# NSUnarchiver in iOS

Tags: ios, macos

I have a NSData object was archived by NSArchiver in OSX, it was a NSAttributedString. Now I want to unarchive it in iOS, but iOS has no NSUnarchiver, it only has NSKeyedUnarchiver which doesn't fit the job.

Is it even possible to decode the data? I want to implement NSUnarchiver myself but how I suppose to figure out those magic bytes in the NSData?

Answer (score 0):

Of course iOS has both NSKeyedUnarchiver and NSKeyedArchiver. It won't make any sense if they had offered archiver with no unarchiver.

Suppose, the name of your NSData property or variable is myData, here is how you can encode and decode them:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:myData forKey:@"myData"];
}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        [self setMyData:[aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"myData"]];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Then you can make a file path where you are persisting it:

```
NSString *cachePath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
cachePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Store.archive"];
```

Now you need to decide where in your program you are archiving and unarchiving the data. There you can use the following:

UnArchiver:

```
ClassName *cachedObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:cachePath];
```

Archiver:

```
[NSKeyedArchiver archiveRootObject:theObjectYourWantToArchive toFile:cachePath];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Please read the question again. The archive was created with NSArchiver, not NSKeyedArchiver. As the OP points out, iOS doesn't have the non-keyed versions of these classes.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I think you got me wrong. I know that iOS has `NSKeyedUnarchiver`, but my NSData object was archived by `NSArchiver` in OS X platform, not `NSKeyedArchiver`. I need `NSUnArchiver` to unarchive it, `NSKeyedUnarchiver` can't get this job done. I'm thinking about is there any chance to implement `NSUnarchiver` myself.